# In Quantum mechanics, what is realism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Some interpretations of QM are realist and some are anti-realist. But, it is the idea that something exists before it is measured, correct?

Comment: This belongs into philosophy, not physics.

Comment: @CuriousOne: As much as I would like to agree, "quantum interpretations" are a part of physics, for better or worse. To OP: What about googling the word "realism" did not satisfy you, and could you make this into a question that has an answer other than Yes/No?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "Quantum realism" is not even part of interpretations. The testable physics side of Copenhagen ends at the Born rule. After that it's all philosophy with a touch of math and zero testable physical content.  Is it philosophy of science? Maybe, but it is not physics that can be connected to any experiment I am aware of. One can, by the way, ask the same question in classical mechanics and Plato has given us a satisfactory answer 2500 years ago. Nothing that has been said about "reality" since then has changed anything fundamental about it.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Rather by definition, I think interpretations are *never* distinguished by experiment (which is why I wish they would just go away), and yet it belongs to "physics" in the sense of "what physicists do". I wholeheartedly agree that they rarely, if ever, are *science*, though.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: And that's why they are not covered by the definition of science. If I can't rule something out, it's not called a hypothesis. If it's not a hypothesis, it has no business in science. Physics is not what physicists do, otherwise gardening and playing squash would be physics and so would laughing at silly movies be.

Comment: @CuriousOne, you seem to be taking this to a strange place. The OP is clearly asking about clarifying some terminology used in various interpretations of QM. Rather than berate philosophy, perhaps we ought to answer the question?

Comment: @AlexNelson: I clearly stated that this isn't physics and the logical reasons why it isn't are obvious. To me this isn't even worth discussing. The rules of the site clearly state that philosophy doesn't belong here.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm not going to debate you on something you're clearly emotional about; although it is amusingly ironic, you appeal *to philosophy* (Popper's criteria for science) to pathologically decry philosophy. Since you cannot rationally form a coherent position, nor are you contributing anything constructive to the question, perhaps you should just get off your soap box and stop...yes yes, **you** believe interpretations of QM should belong to philosophy, blah blah, duly noted.

Comment: @AlexNelson: The definition of science was well established before Popper wrote it down and sold it as his own. Am I talking to a philosophy fanboy with science envy right now? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne that is only naively true.

Comment: @Danu: You mean that we all had to wait for Popper to show us the ropes? Yes, that would be a very naive thought, indeed, and quite self-depricating. I like to go with the hypothesis that fits the data better and doesn't strain Occam's razor as much, that philosophy since Spinoza was an intellectually empty exercise.

Comment: @CuriousOne Allow me to retort in a fashion equally condescending as your remark: Ignorance is bliss.

Comment: @Danu: That's exactly what I said about philosophy. We are in 100% agreement.

Answer (score 1):

I find it very curious that our local philosophers of science can not answer this problem and don't even attempt to answer it after getting upset about being told that this is a matter for philosophy. So let me tell you a little bit about my observations as a physicist about the source of the problem. By observation, of course, I am talking about the observations of the behavior of people who are engaging in fruitless discussions about things like the nature of the universe or the construction of perpetual motion machines, both of which can be explained by a psychological phenomenon I call "degeneracy blindness".

What do I mean by "degeneracy"? In this context a "degeneracy" is the independence of a physical fact of a variable that is perceived to be important. Let me illustrate this with a neutral example of a real case that I was involved in recently. A person came to me with a formula which was essentially a modeling function $f(r, s, t)$, where $r$ and $s$ were well motivated physical parameters and $t$ was a time variable. Interestingly, the two parameters only entered the function $f$ as a product $rs$, i.e. we were really dealing with $f(rs, t)$. The person asked me to use the data set he had measured (i.e. a list of values $f_i, t_i$) to fit the parameters $r$ and $s$ independently. I looked at the functional dependence of his model and told him that that was not possible based on the data about $f$ alone. He kept insisting that the model parameters were well motivated and that the theory was sound. I kept repeating that the model was degenerate in both parameters and that it really only depended on their product. After hours of discussion I gave up trying to convince this intelligent person that he didn't have enough data/model to determine both parameters independently.

Let's go one step further. If we know one thing about the universe, it's that it is completely invariant against translation in both space and time. Galileo knew this (or suspected it strongly). Newton knew this. 18th and 19th century physicists knew this. And what did they do? Despite all of this knowledge they kept looking for a mystical "absolute space" that could break this degeneracy! To this day scores of folks who don't understand Noether's theorem are dreaming about "free energy" and perpetual motion, even if it flies into the face of the translational degeneracy of reality!

How does this relate to quantum mysticism? Very simple. We know that quantum mechanics is essentially the study of linear superpositions of states. The concepts of Hilbert spaces and operators are nothing but advanced linear algebra. At the heart you can see the whole exercise as a choice of base, followed by a choice of coefficients followed by a linear mapping (the time evolution of the system) followed by a linear projection onto a subspace. Rinse, repeat. There is no absolute set of states in QM from which the world evolves in a classical manner. It's rotate, project, rotate, project. The further evolution of a quantum system is completely degenerate about anything that happens in the complement of the projection space. And yet, what do quantum mystics do all day? They can not let go of the idea (which has been thoroughly rejected by nature), that there has to be some "reality" to the degenerate part of the system's configuration space. They keep telling us that if we just add another delayed choice or another weak measurement to the 17 delayed choices and 42 weak measurements that they have added to their latest incarnation of the "quantum reality machine", that then, finally, the birdie will come out!

The birdie doesn't come out. There is no birdie. There is no way to break the degeneracy in my friend's $f(rs,t)$ function. There is no way to break the degeneracy of relative spacetime which gives us energy and momentum conservation. There is no way to break the state degeneracy of QM, which simply doesn't let us look behind the curtain, because there is not even a curtain.

And yet, in all of these examples you can find the psychological phenomenon of "degeneracy blindness", where someone of reasonable intelligence and education just can't believe that the math that describes the world correctly doesn't care about the particular piece of additional information that is their heart's desire.

You want to talk about philosophy? Go back to what Plato wanted. He wanted to get out of the cave, even after having identified its working principles correctly. That, too, was "degeneracy blindness".

Comment: In your opinion, what are the conditions under which a projection occurs?

Comment: It's not in my opinion but in that of the Born rule. The Born rule doesn't mean, of course, that we are really doing anything special to the system or, as some claim, to the universe when we are making a measurement. All it means is that an attempt to measure a classical variable will result in what looks like a projection. The Born rule, if you will, is the best description of a shadow on the cave wall that we have ever encountered.

Comment: So state vector projection occurs when someone looks at the wall of Plato's cave... OK.

Comment: Does a shadow on a cave wall dance when nobody looks at it?