# Do electrons have a location before they are observed/measured?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

Is this in all interpretations of QM? What about interpretations that are realist (MWI, penrose, ect)?

Comment: No. They don't have a location after they have been measured, either. An electron is a quantum state, not a classical object.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155422/2451

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you about the standard QM approach vis-à-vis Bohm's interpretation. (Penrose's is not known to me and MWI says that at a measurement of a microscopic particle, position measurement of an electron in your question, **all** the possible results are obtained, each result in **another world**. But with MWI I don't deal.)

Now, the standard QM doesn't admit a precise position before the measurement, unless the wave-function is a delta function $\delta (x - x_0)$.

Bohm's interpretation says that **yes**, before the measurement the electron had a position before measurement, and **there** where it was, **there** it is found.

But let me give you some more details about this interpretation. It can be found in his articles

D. Bohm, "A Suggested Interpretation of the Quantum Theory in Terms of "Hidden" Variables. I", Phys.Rev., vol. 85, no. 2, page 166, (January 15, 1952),

and

D. Bohm, "A Suggested Interpretation of the Quantum Theory in Terms of "Hidden" Variables. II", Phys.Rev., vol. 85, no. 2, page 180, (January 15, 1952).

I recommend for the beginning the article I. Bohm obtains from the wave-function written in a special form, and introduced in the Schrodinger equation, a Hamilton-Jacobi equation similar to the classical one, but in which besides the potential in the nature (if there is such a one, Bohm obtains a "quantum potential". The latter is some construction obtained from the wave-function, and in simple words, it tells us where the particle can be found, and where not.

In Bohm's interpretation, particles follow well-defined trajectories from source to detector, and considering many particles identically prepared they produce the same statistics as the one predicted by the QM.

P.S. I didn't say that this interpretation is fully satisfactory.

Comment: What about experiment with just one electron at a time? This low intensity electron stream can produce diffraction pattern also...I think that usual interpretation is fully satisfactory.

Comment: When I said "many particles identically prepared", I didn't say that they fall on the photographic plate all of them at once. It is a bad procedure because the particle may interact among themselves and the wave-function is no more correct. About "usual interpretation" I don't know, which is usual, I know the standard QM. I referred in my answer to it.

Comment: Ok, agreed. I was just wondering about other interpretations and how they account for this, and in a way agreeing with you.

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić : you say half things and I have difficulty in understanding. You say "and how they account for this". Please be more clear, what is the "this"? I am trying to answer, but for that, I have to understand the question. By the way, there is one more interpretation, that of Ghirardi, Rimini and Weber. They simulate the collapse by modifying the Schrodinger equation. I ponder whether to refer to it too in my answer, but I am against long answers.